# I tried to send both Http response and WebSocket message in the same controller, and only one of them can be sent correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I am using WebSocket to design a notification system, and for testing purposes, I uses `simpMessagingTemplate` in one of the controller to see if the ws message could be sent correctly. However, only the http response of that controller was sent, the ws message never showed up. After some testing, I found that once I made the controller return nothing(`Result<List<ImgVo>>` to `void`), the ws message could be sent correctly, and I am very confused about this behavior. As far as I know, WebSocket connection is different from the Http connection, and when my frontend starts loading, it would establish a connection with backend WebSocket, and that connection would be alive as long as both applications are alive. And when a Http request reaches that controller, a http connection is established, and the controller would first send the ws message via the existing WebSocket connection created earlier, then it would send the http response via the http connection made in that controller, so there shouldn't be any conflict, but this is the result I got. Please explain to me if I am wrong, thanks.

```
//This only returns Http Response, no WebSocket message is received in the frontend
@GetMapping("/index_imgs")
        public Result<List<ImgVo>> listIndexImgs(){
            List<ImgVo> indexImgVos = indexImgService.listIndexImgs();
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic", "test msg");
            return Result.success(indexImgVos);
        }

//Changing return type to void makes the WebSocket Message sent correctly. Why???
@GetMapping("/index_imgs")
        public void listIndexImgs(){
            List<ImgVo> indexImgVos = indexImgService.listIndexImgs();
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic", "test msg");
        }
```

My WebSocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-endpoint").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-endpoint").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Frontend:

```
const client = new StompJs.Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint',
    onConnect: () => {
      client.subscribe('/topic', message =>
        console.log(`Received: ${message.body}`)
      );
    },
  });
```